# How to stop annoying documentation popups in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA 15, I get these constant and annoying documentation popups whenever my mouse is anywhere in the code window for a decompiled class (from a 3rd party jar). It will popup docs for whatever variable/method/class/anything happens to be near my mouse. If my mouse is not near any lines of code, it will popup for the current classfile, so basically I can't browse code unless I move my mouse to another window.

It only happens with decompiled classes, not my normal code. How do I stop these?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Go to File>Settings>Editor>General - in the section 'Other', uncheck 'Show quick documentation on mouse move'.

In later versions of IntelliJ, the path is File>Settings>Editor>Code Editing, and it is under the "Quick Documentation" section.

Comment: I still want quick documentation when my mouse is actually over something that has docs, I just don't want it anytime my mouse is anywhere in the code window. Quick docs should work the same for decompiled classes as they do for regular classes - but they don't. Is this a bug?

Comment: I actually found this issue in their tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155519. They claim that it is fixed in later versions.

Comment: What if it is unchecked but pops up every time the IDE starts up

Comment: Check File>Settings>Editor>General->Code Completion->Show the documentation popup in 1000ms. But this may not work, the bug several years old  
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=mouse%20documentation%20popup

Answer (score 37):

In my cause, 'Show quick documentation on mouse move' was in Editor > Code Editing:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want the documentation bubble but not the popup window, do this:

Place your text cursor on some text which causes the popup.

Press ctrl + q (or whatever keyboard shortcut you have for quick documentation) a couple of times until the popup window disappears, the quick documentation will then revert to the "bubble" on  hover.

Answer (score 5):

Under the `File/Settings/..`, at the top search bar, type in for `"Quick Documentation"`, will point to the location.
[image]

Comment: Is there a checkbox in 'quick documentation' that you can use to turn it off?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For instance, you can add a screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

Press **<F1>** button to show/hide this pop-up.